# Registerbutton is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsf

I'm facing one problem with `h:commandButton` is not working with Google Chrome. Please see the below code

```
<h:commandButton 
   id="btnReg" 
   value="#{msgs.testtube_registration_button_registration}"
   action="#{testTubeRegistrationBean.register}" 
   rendered="#{testTubeRegistrationBean.ufmTesttubeReg.addRecordYn==1
             && testTubeRegistrationBean.ttRegistration.id == 0
             || testTubeRegistrationBean.ttRegistration.id == null}" 
   styleClass="inputBtn" 
   onmouseover="this.className='inputBtnHover'" 
   onmouseout="this.className='inputBtn'">                        
</h:commandButton>
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: And please make an [mcve]...

Comment: and you are (indirectly) saying it works in Firefox?

Comment: No it is not working in firefox as well.It's working IE 8 and below.I'm adding the code again here